# C++ and printf - strange character output

Tags: c++, console-application, printf

I'm a complete newb to C++, but not to Java, C#, JavaScript, VB. I'm working with a default C++ console app from Visual Studio 2010.

In trying to do a printf I get some strange characters. Not the same each time which tells me they may be looking at different memory location each time I run it.

Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Person
{
public:
    string first_name;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char somechar;
    Person p;
    p.first_name = "Bruno";

    printf("Hello %s", p.first_name);
    scanf("%c",&somechar);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `cout` in C++. For printf with %s you would need `p.first_name.c_str()` but don't use `printf` in C++.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that `printf`/`scanf` are not typesafe. You're supplying a `std::string` object where `printf` expects a `const char*`.

One way to fix this is to write

```
printf("Hello %s", p.first_name.c_str());
```

However, since you're coding in C++, it's a good idea to use I/O streams in preference to `printf`/`scanf`:

```
std::cout << p.first_name << std::endl;
std::cin >> c;
```

Comment: Thanks +1. So is there a formatting equivalent to printf in C++?

Answer (score 4):

Convert the string to a c-string.

```
printf("Hello %s", p.first_name.c_str());
```

Also, since you're using C++, you should learn about cout as opposed to printf!

Comment: +1 for answering the question and then pushing him in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Use `printf("Hello %s",p.first_name.c_str());`!

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("Hello %s", p.first_name.c_str());
```

However, why aren't you using iostream, if you are using c++?

Comment: +1 because I'm such a newb. Breaking out my C++ books out again as we speak.

Comment: Because iostream is very very very very damn slow compared to printf(). Does a lots of things that you do not need. Google!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass C++ `std::string` objects into `printf`.  `printf` only understands the primitive types like `int`, `float`, and `char*`.  Your compiler *should* be giving you a warning there; if it's not, crank up your warning level.

Since you're using C++, you really should be using `std::cout` for text output, and that does understand `std::string` objects.  If you really have to use `printf` for some reason, then convert the `std::string` to a `const char*` by calling the `c_str()` method on it.

Answer (score 0):

`printf("%s")` accepts a c-style string which is terminated by a `'\0'`. However, `string` object is C++ object which is different from a c-style string. You should use `std::cout` which is overloaded to handle `string` type directly, as shown below.

```
std::cout << p.first_name;
```

Comment: OK, so you demonstrated how to output the first name. What about the word "Hello"?

Comment: @Jim, for "Hello" OP already did it right w/ printf. You should try identity the main part of the question, ignoring the other trivial parts. Right?